# Editing wp-login.php

Tags: login

I'm looking to alter the message "Please enter your username or email address. You will receive an email message with instructions on how to reset your password" in the wp-login file.

If I change this directly I assume it'll revert back after a WordPress update. Is there a way to make it permanent or a plugin I can install to edit it from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`login_message` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_message/) will allow you to change the message persisting through WordPress updates. I usually use an mu-plugin, but the below can also be added to your theme's `functions.php`.

Untested:

```php
add_filter( 'login_message', static function ( $message ) {
    $action = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';

    if ( ! in_array( $action, array( 'lostpassword', 'retrievepassword' ) ) ) {
        return $message;
    }

    return __( 'Your preferred message.' );
} );
```

You could compare directly to the core message as well, but that seems less reliable (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'login_message', static function ( $message ) {
    $default = __( 'Please enter your username or email address. You will receive an email message with instructions on how to reset your password.' );

    if ( $default !== $message ) {
        return $message;
    }

    return __( 'Your preferred message.' );
} );
```